# Visual Studio: How to deploy a solution and continue developing it

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a solution that I would like to run each day, but simultaneously continue development on it.  While it is running, when I attempt to build a new version I receive the error that "Unable to copy file "obj\x86\Debug\Solution.exe" to "bin\Debug\Solution.exe". The process cannot access the file . . . ".  This is perfectly understandable: the currently running version has a lock on the .exe, so a new one cannot be created.

My question is this:  what is the best practice to "release" the current version to run each day, while keeping a separate "debug" version available for development?  My current approach is to create a separate copy of the project, but that is very tedious.  Is there a better way?

Thank you,
Ben.

Answer (score 3):

Build a Release Version, run it from folder. (Set Solution Configuration to Release)
Develop and debug in debug mode.

Comment: Set the output directory in Release builds to a production location that is different from Debug.

Comment: thank you all.  these are exactly the suggestions I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a Winforms or WPF app you can right click on your project, click on Properties and go to Publish tab. From there you can publish your app to a UNC path, install from there and run it while continuing development from within the Visual Studio IDE.

Edit: Additional advantage of this approach is that when you have a new version you will be able to publish to the same location and the next time you start your app it will be automatically updated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any source control system?  It's not clear if your problem is simply the mechanics of making a build, or how to keep a copy of your source that corresponds to each build.  If the answer is b, then a source control system is designed to solve this problem.

You would make a build each day and publish/release the binaries, while at the same time checking in your source code.  That way you have a "copy" of your source code that corresponds to each released build, while still allowing you to continue active development.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a post-build script to simply copy the resulting EXE to a new location. You can run it from there easy enough. You can even execute it in the script if you don't like double-clicking ;)